# jQuery + regex. How to use quotation marks to print HTML code?

Tags: jquery, regex

I just don't get this right. How do I use quotation marks to get this work?

```
$("div a').replaceWith('<a href="#" onclick="'+data['hash']+'")>Link</a>');
```

I have tried for example this and other variations:

```
 $("div a').replaceWith('<a href="#" onclick="'+data[/\'hash/\']+'")>Link</a>');
```

I'm far from being regex expert...

EDIT:

Actually the line is this now:

```
$("div a").replaceWith('<a href="#" onclick="share('+data['hash']+')")>Link</a>');
```

Sorry for confusion. That still doesn't work in my HTML code. Like @T.J.Crowder mentioned, it needs to be HTML encoded so I did this, but didn't work:

```
$("div a").replaceWith('<a href="#" onclick="share('+data['hash']+')")>Link</a>').html();
```

Comment: Did you noticed that the code you pasted it's not colored / highlighted pretty well? This should already tell you something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by balancing the quotes you're using in the initial selector.

```
$("div a")
//      ^---- ", not '
```

Then remove the extraneous `)`, and you get:

```
$("div a").replaceWith('<a href="#" onclick="'+data['hash']+'">Link</a>');
//                     ^                     ^              ^          ^
// These delimit the html string; the " within them are part of the HTML
```

This may be clearer if we put each segment on its own line:

```
$("div a").replaceWith(
    '<a href="#" onclick="' +
    data['hash'] +
    '">Link</a>'
);
```

But note that whatever value you have stored in `data['hash']` will need to be HTML-encoded (as it's the value of an HTML attribute) *and* will need not to have any `'` in it. You haven't shown what that is, so...

Comment: The data['hash'] is simply this: 9914251535107a615e77e6e2cc0f929d7002a266 ...for example. So it need to be HTML-encoded? Sounds acceptable because I didn't get my code working yet. But your answer was correct. Thank you! @T.J.Crowder

Comment: @hemppa: `9914251535107a615e77e6e2cc0f929d7002a266` isn't valid JavaScript code, so if you put it in the `onclick` attribute, clicking that div will cause an error.

Comment: ah... sorry I have defined that share-function elsewhere. That hash number is only the parameter of that function which needs to be updated. @T.J. Crowder

Answer (score 0):

Change "div a' to 'div a':

```
$('div a').replaceWith('<a href="#" onclick="'+data['hash']+'")>Link</a>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('div a').replaceWith("<a href='#' onclick='"+data['hash']()+"'>Link</a>");
```

Note:

I use single quotes on the inside because I don't have to press `shift` as much. I'm assuming `data['hash']` holds an unexecuted function.

Answer (score 0):

Looks fine after you changed the code as Crowder suggested:

```
$("div a").replaceWith('<a href="#" onclick="share('+data['hash']+')")>Link</a>').html();
```

He also asked about `data['hash']`  . This should be html encoded, if it is not already then change it like this: ( I also see one extra ')' there )

```
$("div a").replaceWith('<a href="#" onclick="share( escape ( '+data['hash']+') ) ")>Link</a>').html();
//By the way is this an extra ')' you have   -------------------------------------^
```